# How to read Data from a TBlobField using ADO in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ado

I was trying to read data from a TBlobField using TADOBlobStream. I wrote the following function

```
function DecompressBlobFieldCustom(AField:TBlobField):String;
    var
      BLOBStream:TADOBlobStream;
      Size:Integer;
    begin
      BLOBStream:= TADOBlobStream.Create(AField,bmRead);
      Size:= BLOBStream.Size;
      BLOBStream.Read(Result,Size);
    end;
```

and i use the function as follows

```
 Data := DecompressBlobFieldCustom(FldImage);
```

But when i try to do `if Length(Data) > 0 then` i am getting `Access violation at address XXXX` error. I couldn't figure out the problem. Please Help.

Comment: where do you destroy(free) `BLOBStream` object ? where do you set the `Result` size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Result` is a string type, but a blob stream operates on byte arrays. It is usually a mistake to try to treat a byte array as though it were a string. Furthermore, you did not allocate a buffer into which to read, which is the actual cause of the error.

Read into a byte array like this:

```
function ReadBlobField(Field: TBlobField): TBytes;
var
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Stream := TADOBlobStream.Create(Field, bmRead);
  try
    SetLength(Result, Stream.Size);
    if Stream.Size>0 then
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Result[0], Stream.Size);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It is preferable to use the `CreateBlobStream` method of `TDataSet` to create blob streams, as discussed in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.CreateBlobStream). So the code would be better like this:

```
function ReadBlobField(DataSet: TDataSet; Field: TField): TBytes;
var
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Stream := DataSet.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmRead);
  try
    SetLength(Result, Stream.Size);
    if Stream.Size>0 then
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Result[0], Stream.Size);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I've assumed that the data really is a byte array and is not holding text. The fact that it is held in a blob suggests that, as does the mention of decompression and images.

Some other comments:

1. You must destroy the stream when you are finished with it.
2. It is generally preferable to use `ReadBuffer` rather than `Read` because `ReadBuffer` raises an exception if the requested number of bytes are not read.

Comment: getting a compilation error  Element 0 inaccessible - use 'Length' or 'SetLength' at the   line Stream.Read(Result[0], Stream.Size);

Comment: Not with the code you can see here. Use the code in my answer rather than your code which is broken. Don't just take randomly selected parts of the code in my answer, and apply them to your code. Programming doesn't work that way. Use the functions in the answer in their entirety. Take heed of the fact that a byte array is not a string.

Comment: My BlobField Conatins TextData. I found a function in uCompression unit as followes          function DecompressBlobField(AField: TBlobField): String; overload;
var
  SourceStream: TBlobStream;
begin
  CheckAssigned(AField, NoBlobFieldMsg);
  SourceStream := TBlobStream.Create(AField, bmRead);
  try
    Result := DecompressStream(SourceStream);
  finally
    SourceStream.Free;
  end;
end;   How that function is able to return a string?. Actually i want the Result as a string.

Comment: All of this is way outside the scope of what was asked in the question. Do you know anything about text encodings? Do you know how the data in the blob field was compressed? Or are you just trying stuff at random?

Comment: Actually i don't know how the text data is encoded in the Blob Field. I am new to this.  "The data need to be decompressed first before using that" is that what you meant ?

Comment: You are going to need to work out these missing details. I certainly can't tell you how the data was compressed. I dealt with the access violation which was the subject of the question. It's unreasonable to expect extended consequential debugging support. Over to you.

Comment: ya i understood these are different from my question. But your answer is right for the question i asked.I will look into the details and debug. Thanks for the Help :-)